# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'initializeApp')

Tags: javascript, firebase

For some reason i keep apporaching this error whenever i run this code:

```
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAnalytics, logEvent } from "firebase/analytics";
import { getAuth, connectAuthEmulator,  GoogleAuthProvider } from "firebase/auth";
import { firebase } from '@firebase/app';
import { getFirestore, collection, addDoc, doc, getDoc } from "firebase/firestore";


// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "*"
  authDomain: "*",
  databaseURL: "*",
  projectId: "*",
  storageBucket: "*",
  messagingSenderId: "*",
  appId: "*",
  measurementId: "*"
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = getAuth();
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
const db = getFirestore(app);
const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
export const signInWithGoogle = () => auth.signInWithPopup(provider);

export { db, analytics, collection, addDoc, doc, getDoc, logEvent };
```

I tried installing the newest firebase, updating, changing my import statements... nothing ive tried seems to work and I've been searching for a solution for a few days.

Comment: It looks like `firebase/app` only exports `firebase`, not `initializeApp`. You should just use `firebase.initializeApp()`, not a top-level `initializeApp()`.

Comment: @Barmar No, it's the other way around. They should use the initializeApp function that was imported, as you can see from the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#add-sdks-initialize).

Comment: @DougStevenson Of course. I should have realized that when the error message said "cannot read property of undefined" rather than saying that undefined is not a function.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/69503537, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69028571/in-firebase-i-am-getting-an-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-initialize and more results

Answer (score 1):

When using the latest Firebase web SDK, this is not correct:

```
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

You should initialize the SDK using the initializeApp function that you already imported:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

Please refer to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#add-sdks-initialize) for further examples.

This import isn't going to help you at all:

```
import { firebase } from '@firebase/app';
```